# does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: c#, async-await, api-eveonline

Im getting the below error with the below set of code, It is erroring on the 'alliancelookup' line, I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but I couldn't see anything myself. The query im running to crest seems to be running fine but It seems the issue im having is with the Awaiter, I was wondering if there was a way around this?

```
DynamicCrest crest = new DynamicCrest();
var root = await crest.GetAsync(crest.Host);
var alliancelookup = await (await root.GetAsync(r => r.alliances)).First(i => i.shortName == e.GetArg("allianceticker").ToUpper());
allianceid = alliancelookup.id;
```

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'
>      at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>      at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
>      at ***.Program.<>c.<b__2_10>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users---\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects------\Program.cs:line 95

Comment: It would help to know what line 95 is. The error you get is pretty straight forward. What ever object you are trying to `await` does not properly implement the `GetAwaiter` method that is required for the while thing to work.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible to know exactly what's wrong without a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but it does look like you're `await`ing something that isn't meant to be `await`ed.

Splitting up the `alliancelookup` line:

```
// Asynchronously retrieve the alliances.
var alliances = await root.GetAsync(r => r.alliances);

// Synchronously get the first matching one.
var allianceLookup = alliances.First(i => i.shortName == e.GetArg("allianceticker").ToUpper());
```

There may be a better approach, moving the filter into the async code, but that depends on `DynamicCrest`.

Answer (score 2):

You have one more await than what you need. You only have to await the async methods, but you also are awaiting the result, which apparently declared type is `dynamic`. That's why you are not getting a compile time error.

With `dynamic` it will try to bind the method that needs at runtime. That method when using async is .GetAwaiter(), an thus the RuntimeBinderException "does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'"

That said, the third line should be:

```
var alliancelookup = (await root.GetAsync(r => r.alliances)).First(i => i.shortName == e.GetArg("allianceticker").ToUpper());
```

Although splitting up as suggested by Stephen Cleary is a better practice.

Comment: This helped me. I was awaiting the async method's result (method.Result) which has declared type of dynamic. Removing the .Result worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are awaiting a asyn call so you have to put async Task at the beginning of the method where you are calling this code

```
public async Task<returntyp> Name()
{
  DynamicCrest crest = new DynamicCrest();
  var root = await crest.GetAsync(crest.Host);
  var alliancelookup = await (await root.GetAsync(r => r.alliances)).First(i => i.shortName == e.GetArg("allianceticker").ToUpper());
  allianceid = alliancelookup.id;
```

Comment: If there wasn't `async` there would be a compile error, not a runtime one.